# Why isn't my Python calculator working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

When I execute and run the code the program doesn't seem to store the c input, therefore not continuing the code to perform the rest of the calculator function.

```
def calc():

    print("Press 1 for addition")
    print("Press 2 for subtraction")
    print("Press 3 for multiplication")
    print("Press 4 for division")

    c = input()

    if c == 1:
        print("Enter a number")
        x = input()
        print("Enter another number")
        y = input()
        return x + y

    elif c == 2:
        print("Enter a number")
        x = input()
        print("Enter another number")
        y = input()
        return x - y

    elif c == 3:
        print("Enter a number")
        x = input()
        print("Enter another number")
        y = input()
        return x * y

    elif c == 4:
        print("Enter a number")
        x = input()
        print("Enter another number")
        y = input()
        return x / y

calc()
```

I've now improved the code but can't seem to get the indentation right and it seems that the return function on each type of math that is being performed is 'outside function'

```
def calc():
print("Press 1 for addition")
print("Press 2 for subtraction")
print("Press 3 for multiplication")
print("Press 4 for division")

c = int(input())

def get_inputs():
    print("Enter a number")
    x = int(input())
    print("Enter another number")
    y = int(input())
    return x, y

if c == 1:
    x, y = get_inputs()
    return x + y #These return functions seem to be an error

elif c == 2:
    x, y = get_inputs()
    return x - y

elif c == 3:
    x, y = get_inputs()
    return x * y

elif c == 4:
    x, y = get_inputs()
    return x / y

calc()
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string in Python 3; you want an integer `c = int(input())`

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` in Python 3 is same as `raw_input()` in Python 2.7 which returns object of `str` type. You need to explicitly type-cast it to `int`

```
 c = int(input())
```

Comment: This doesn't address all problems and doesn't explain why it's needed..

Answer (score 0):

First, use `c = int(input())` instead to convert the input string to integer.
Also, just to make the program cleaner, since you're already using functions (`calc`), might as well put the input part for each operation in a function:

```
def get_inputs():
    print("Enter a number")
    x = int(input())
    print("Enter another number")
    y = int(input())
    return x, y
```

And then for each operation do something like:

```
if c == 1:
    a, b = get_inputs()
    return a + b
```

(Edit) try this:

```
def get_inputs():
    print("Enter a number")
    x = int(input())
    print("Enter another number")
    y = int(input())
    return x, y

def calc():
    print("Press 1 for addition")
    print("Press 2 for subtraction")
    print("Press 3 for multiplication")
    print("Press 4 for division")

    c = int(input())

    if c == 1:
        x, y = get_inputs()
        return x + y

    elif c == 2:
        x, y = get_inputs()
        return x - y

    elif c == 3:
        x, y = get_inputs()
        return x * y

    elif c == 4:
        x, y = get_inputs()
        return x / y

calc()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but now I am having indentation issues with this. Still new and getting used to how indents work.

Comment: Where are you having indentation issues?

Comment: The get_inputs() on each math function